# Truncate cube of double

Tags: c#

I would like to truncate a cube.

If I have a 1d array I can do this:

```
var oldarray = new double[n];
var newarray = new double[m];

Array.Copy(oldarray, newarray, m);
```

for m smaller n, obviously oldarray would store some data...

I would like to do the same on a cube, like:

```
var oldarray = new double[n,n,n];
var newarray = new double[m,m,m];

Array.Copy(oldarray, newarray, m);
```

Whats the fastest (most performant) way please? (apart from using a triple for loop) thanks.

Comment: Calling Array.Copy with the right index/length arguments `m` times (or is it `m^2`?) should work http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/z50k9bft(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: so essetially instead of a triple loop I do a double loop and copy vector by vector?

Comment: its a cube, so if m=10 then it is ten 10by10 squares. or what do you mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could still use [`Array.Copy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z50k9bft%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), but then the multi-dimensional one:

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < m ; i++)
{
    Array.Copy(oldarray, i, newarray, i, oldarray.GetLength(i));
}
```